# How to populate the data from database using popup

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am working on project.in which i want to fetch data by clientid and populate it to the rest fields.(just for user convenience).i have done with it.but its not working on a popup.and body suggest me the good way or guide me where i am doing the mistake.

html code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Client Id
        </th>
        <th>
            Client Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Client Number
        </th>
        <th>
            Address
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type='text' id="countryname_1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type='text' id="country_no_1"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type='text' id="phone_code_1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type='text' id="country_code_1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ajax code:

```
<?php    
require_once 'config.php';
if($_POST['type'] == 'country_table'){
    $row_num = $_POST['row_num'];
    $name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
    $query = "SELECT clientId, clientName, contactNo, address FROM clients";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['clientId'].'|'.$row['clientName'].'|'.$row['contactNo'].'|'.$row['address'].'|'.$row_num;
        array_push($data, $name);   
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);
}?>
```

this code is working individually.not in the popup.any suggestion

Comment: How do you display the popup?

Comment: @dewaldcels i have an extrenal page fot the whole links.when user add a new task then the popup is shown.

Comment: i have a page of index there all the links are called.

Comment: Is the HTML you provided the popup layout? How do you execute the AJAX request to run the PHP code?

Comment: Did you ever sort out your issue Muhammad?